# Windows crashes with memory-management stopcode persist through reformat

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, bsod, memory-management

For the past ~half year, my desktop has been crashing occasionally. Windows goes to a blue screen, with the stopcode MEMORY_MANAGEMENT before crashing. I believe that I've seen a couple of different stopcodes as well, but I never wrote them down. Sometimes, applications will behave very strangely or act unresponsive in weird ways. In one case, no application was able to play media. I went to youtube, netflix, and spotify and none of their play buttons were responsive. I tried restarting the computer when I saw this, and got the blue screen before it shut down. More commonly, I notice a weird graphical error in an application and get the blue screen when restart.

My initial reaction to issues with this computer is to just reformat and reinstall windows, because I keep no important data on it. I did, and the issue has persisted (I use a lot of the same drivers/software as before the reformat). I also ran memtest86 for at least 3 hours, but it didn't find anything wrong.

At this point, I still think is an issue with RAM or a driver but I would like to be assured before spending more money on a replacement RAM.

Comment: .....memtest64?

Comment: Have you tried reseating your RAM ? You can also try the microsoft's memtest: use windows search for "Windows Memory Diagnostic" or run "mdsched".

Comment: @Bib uhh I think I've made a mistake (can't remember but I do think i used 86

Comment: @Silbee I didn't know there is such a thing as resetting ram! Will look into both, thanks.

Comment: @Dejke Reseating = removing and reinstalling the RAM.

Comment: @Silbee aha, makes sense